# PreferenceFragment OnPreferenceClickListener() works only once

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, onclicklistener, reset

I'm implementing a custom `Preference` that shall behave similar to a button (the preference will open up a dialog for restoring the default values of all preferences).
It's working fine if you click on the `ResetPreference` the dialog shows and on positive click all preference data is cleared and reset, **but** if you click on the `ResetPreference` again nothing happens. I suppose that while setting the `PreferenceScreen` to null and re-adding the resources something is amiss.

If you ask why I used this approach, I wanted to click on reset and directly show the result of the change, if anyone knows a better way to implement a reset please give a little example.

PS: If clicking on the `ResetPreference` and selecting the negative button nothing happens and the listener is still functional so it should really have something to to with deleting and re-adding the resources.

**ResetPreference.java**

```
public class ResetPreference extends Preference {

public ResetPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            builder.setTitle(R.string.prefAlertDialog_Title);   
            builder.setMessage(R.string.prefAlertDialog_Message);
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.prefAlertDialog_Positive, new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    SettingsFragment.resetSettings(getContext());   
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.prefAlertDialog_Negative, null);
            builder.create().show();

            return false;
        }
    });

}}
```

Then there is my custom PreferenceFragment
**SettingsFragment.java**

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment{

private static SettingsFragment sf = null;

 public static void resetSettings(Context ctx)
 {

    PreferenceManager
    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx)
    .edit()
    .clear()
    .commit();
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(ctx, R.xml.preferences, true);           

    if(sf != null)
    {
        sf.setPreferenceScreen(null);
        sf.addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);   
    }
 }

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        sf = this;

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        Preference reset = (Preference) findPreference("reset");

        reset.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener()
        {
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference pref)
            {           

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setTitle(R.string.prefAlertDialog_Title);   
                builder.setMessage(R.string.prefAlertDialog_Message);
                builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.prefAlertDialog_Positive, new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
                        .edit()
                        .clear()
                        .commit();
                        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.xml.preferences, true);             

                        setPreferenceScreen(null);
                        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);                      
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.prefAlertDialog_Negative, null);
                builder.create().show();


                return true;
            }
        });
 } 

 @Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    sf = null;
}}
```

---

After adding the suggestion from https://stackoverflow.com/a/24648780/3387852 everything is done in the `SettingsFragment`. The `ResetPreference` is no longer needed and the standard android `Preference` can be used instead.

The only code needed to implement the reset button is in this updated

**SettingsFragment.java**

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment{

private void addMyResetListener() {
    Preference reset = (Preference) findPreference("reset");

    reset.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener()
    {
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference pref)
        {           

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle(R.string.prefAlertDialog_Title);   
            builder.setMessage(R.string.prefAlertDialog_Message);
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.prefAlertDialog_Positive, new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    resetSettings(SettingsFragment.this.getActivity());             
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.prefAlertDialog_Negative, null);
            builder.create().show();

            return true;
        }
    });
}

public void resetSettings(Context ctx)
{   
    //Remove all Settings 
    PreferenceManager
    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx)
    .edit()
    .clear()
    .commit();
    //All Settings that are empty will be loaded from default values again
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(ctx, R.xml.preferences, true);           

    setPreferenceScreen(null);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);  
    addMyResetListener();
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       // Load the preferences from an XML resource & add listener
       addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
       addMyResetListener();
} }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call the `setPreferenceScreen(null);` all the data and listeners of the screens is removed.
Then by calling `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);` you add the data but not the listeners.

So to make `Preference` reset to work you need to add the listener again!

I suggest you create a method

```
private void addMyResetListener() {
    Preference reset = (Preference) findPreference("reset");

    reset.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener()
    {
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference pref)
        {           

            resetSettings(SettingsFragment.this.getActivity());


            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

And use it after the

```
setPreferenceScreen(null);
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
addMyResetListener();
```

So `resetSettings` changes to

```
 public void resetSettings(Context ctx) // also removed static
 {

    PreferenceManager
    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx)
    .edit()
    .clear()
    .commit();
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(ctx, R.xml.preferences, true);           

    setPreferenceScreen(null);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);   
    addMyResetListener();
 }
```

That way you do not need a custom preference `ResetPreference`

Comment: Thanks that works really fine,it looks less confusing and is easy to understand i will put the optimized version (whole Fragment class) in my questen so that others can use it as an easy to understand example.